# Why was this c program converted to assembler like this?

Tags: c, assembly

C Code:

```
int main() {
  __asm__("pushl %eax");
  return 0;
}
```

Converted to assembler:

```
main:
  pushl $ebp
  movl $esp, $ebp
  subl $8, $esp
  ## InlineAsm Start
  pushl $eax
  ## InlineAsm End
  movl $0, -8($ebp)
  movl -8(%ebp), %eax
  movl %eax, -4(%ebp)
  movl -4(%ebp), %eax
  addl $8, %esp
  popl %ebp
  ret
```

I know that the first and last 3 lines are prologue and epilogue, but I don't really understand what the 4 lines after the inline asm do. Can somebody please explain it to me?

Comment: Those four lines `return 0;`.  You compiled without optimisations which is why the code is so weird.  Also note that manipulating the stack pointer from inline assembly is likely causing the code to crash at runtime.

Comment: Is that clang output?  That's particularly terrible, not just storing the `0` to the stack but copying it before reload.  [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) explains why `-O0` code has to suck, but in this case it's just a result of the compiler not even trying.

Comment: `pushl %eax` without a corresponding `pop` will shift the stack top and lead to a crash.